# Короткий переключатель (toggle)

Tags: javascript

При клике меняет значение на *false*, а обратно нет.
Думаю проблема в типе значения, это *string*. Как переделать на *boolean*?

```css
button {
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFF;
  transition: .5s;
}

button[value='true'] { background: #63AEEE; }
button[value='false'] { background: #FF6040; }
```

```html
<button onclick='value = !value' value='true'>Toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так как это все действительно строки, стоит сравнивать со строками.

```css
button {
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFF;
  transition: .5s;
}
button[value='true'] {
  background: #63AEEE;
}
button[value='false'] {
  background: #FF6040;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='value = value == "false";' value='true'>Toggle</button>
```

Значения атрибутов всегда строка, поэтому при присваивании им значения, это значение будет переведено в строку.

Как это работает:

изначально значение `value` - `"true"`

При сравнении: `"true"=="false"` - получаем результат `false`, который при присваивании атрибуту конвертируется в строку `"false"`

При следующем нажатии идет сравнение `"false"=="false"` - получаем результат `true`, который при присваивании атрибуту конвертируется в строку `"true"`.

В итоге вернулись к первоначальному варианту.

Comment: `v = v == ""` а как это работает?

Comment: А, кажется понял. Сравниваем строки и значение от условия возвращается

Comment: @Doofy, добавил описание

Comment: Вот я тогда не знал что условие возвращает `true` или `false` 